# How do I go from an Adobe XD prototype to a working app?

Tags: android-studio-3.0, adobe-xd

I Have Created A Beautiful Design Of My App Using Adobe XD. But Now I Want To Convert That Design Into App That Looks Exact The Same. **How do I go from an Adobe XD prototype to a working app?**

Answer (score 4):

Your question sounds a bit like your searching for a way to convert your design into an app without dealing with the code a lot (in a kind of WYSIWYG-fashion similar to what Adobe Muse does for websites). My answer assumes that that's what you're asking. If not, please feel free to ignore my answer...

Adobe XD is only a design app. This means, that it doesn't really have code generation features. Having said that, there are now a few plugins that can support you in writing this code (e.g. Lightning Storm CC – to my knowledge – supports Android UI export).

Also, as Ash Ryan Arnwine mentioned before, design specs support you when developing the UI (you'll need to code it yourself, though).

All in all, there is no way around either knowing how to code or hiring a developer when creating an Android app. Therefore, these tools can only support you in development, not replace the technical aspect of developing an app. The answer to your question, therefore, is that there, unfortunately (or fortunately – depending on how you look at it?) isn't any way to quickly "convert" a prototype (which really is nothing more than a prototype) into a real app other than coding it yourself (possibly with the assistance of the tools mentioned by Ash Ryan Arnwine and me).

Answer (score 1):

Since there are many unique workflows out there for designers and developers, there's no single answer to your question.

Here are a few things worth looking into:

- [Adobe XD design specs](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/design-specs-for-developers.html): View design specs published from Adobe XD, which enable you to inspect and comment on the flows, measurements, and styles.
- [Adobe XD for Jira Cloud](https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-xd-for-jira-cloud-streamline-design-to-development-workflows): Associate XD prototypes and design specs with Jira issues to keep projects organized and provide developers with everything they need to know right within Jira.
- [Adobe XD plugins](https://theblog.adobe.com/the-new-adobe-xd-ecosystem-supercharging-design-workflows-with-third-party-plugins/): Plugins are coming soon to XD. A couple of common use cases for plugins is designer-developer and design-to-code workflows. If the plugin you want to see isn't when plugins launch, the APIs will be open for anyone to build it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your response to this question: Are you ready to spend money to make this happen? if so, there are two Adobe plugins that try to convert your prototype(anyway, you'll need to code and make efforts in Android Studio). Those plugins are:

- Lightning Storm
- Yotako